# discord.py default help commands show up as a slash command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im struggling with something that seems so simple but I can't figure it out. using discord.py to create a discord bot in python.

I want to make a slash command for help. simple, right? that's what I said 4 hours ago.

I know discord.py has default bot help class but I can't get that to work in the app. and plus I want it to be an actual slash command so that users can easily just type "/help" inside discord. and discord will pull up its ui like any other slash command sorta something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPQIf.png)

so I have tried many things but here is kinda where im at in terms of code:

```
bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="/",
    intents=intents,
)

@bot.tree.command(name="help_command",
                  description="Displays a list of all Commands")
async def help_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(bot.help_command.send_bot_help())
```

- setting help_commands in bot
- using invoke inside @bot.command.

Comment: I am having struggles as well, but i just found a youtube video, maybe this could help us! https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=k-N7NDkJsGg